# android mock gps does not work on real device

Tags: android, gps

I have added:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
```

and the code below:

```
public class MockGpsProviderActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
public static final String LOG_TAG = "MockGpsProviderActivity"; 
private static final String MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX = "GpsMockProviderIndex";

private MockGpsProvider mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
private Integer mMockGpsProviderIndex = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
/* (non-Javadoc)
 * @see android.app.Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    /** Use saved instance state if necessary. */
    if(savedInstanceState instanceof Bundle) {
        /** Let's find out where we were. */
        mMockGpsProviderIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, 0);
    }

    /** Setup GPS. */
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)){ 
        // use real GPS provider if enabled on the device
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }
    else if(!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
        // otherwise enable the mock GPS provider
        locationManager.addTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, false, false,
                false, false, true, false, false, 0, Criteria.ACCURACY_HIGH);
        locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, true);
    }  

    if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER)) {
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

        /** Load mock GPS data from file and create mock GPS provider. */
        try {
            // create a list of Strings that can dynamically grow
            List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

            /** read a CSV file containing WGS84 coordinates from the 'assets' folder
             * (The website http://www.gpsies.com offers downloadable tracks. Select
             * a track and download it as a CSV file. Then add it to your assets folder.)
             */         
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("mock_gps_data.csv");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            // add each line in the file to the list
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                data.add(line);
            }

            // convert to a simple array so we can pass it to the AsyncTask
            String[] coordinates = new String[data.size()];
            data.toArray(coordinates);

            // create new AsyncTask and pass the list of GPS coordinates
            mMockGpsProviderTask = new MockGpsProvider();
            mMockGpsProviderTask.execute(coordinates);
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    // stop the mock GPS provider by calling the 'cancel(true)' method
    try {
        mMockGpsProviderTask.cancel(true);
        mMockGpsProviderTask = null;
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}

    // remove it from the location manager
    try {
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.removeTestProvider(MockGpsProvider.GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {}
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // store where we are before closing the app, so we can skip to the location right away when restarting
    savedInstanceState.putInt(MOCK_GPS_PROVIDER_INDEX, mMockGpsProviderIndex);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // show the received location in the view
    TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    view.setText( "index:" + mMockGpsProviderIndex
            + "\nlongitude:" + location.getLongitude() 
            + "\nlatitude:" + location.getLatitude() 
            + "\naltitude:" + location.getAltitude() );     
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}


@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}


@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
}


/** Define a mock GPS provider as an asynchronous task of this Activity. */
private class MockGpsProvider extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    public static final String LOG_TAG = "GpsMockProvider";
    public static final String GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER = "GpsMockProvider";

    /** Keeps track of the currently processed coordinate. */
    public Integer index = 0;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... data) {         
        // process data
        for (String str : data) {
            // skip data if needed (see the Activity's savedInstanceState functionality)
            if(index < mMockGpsProviderIndex) {
                index++;
                continue;
            }               

            // let UI Thread know which coordinate we are processing
            publishProgress(index);

            // retrieve data from the current line of text
            Double latitude = null;
            Double longitude = null;
            Double altitude= null;
            try {
                String[] parts = str.split(",");
                latitude = Double.valueOf(parts[0]);
                longitude = Double.valueOf(parts[1]);
                altitude = Double.valueOf(parts[2]);
            }
            catch(NullPointerException e) { break; }        // no data available
            catch(Exception e) { continue; }                // empty or invalid line

            // translate to actual GPS location
            Location location = new Location(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER);
            //location.setLatitude(latitude);
            //location.setLongitude(longitude);

            location.setLatitude(39.794952);
            location.setLongitude(116.515134);
            location.setAltitude(10);
            //location.setAccuracy(4);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());

            // show debug message in log
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, location.toString());

            // provide the new location
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(GPS_MOCK_PROVIDER, location);

            // sleep for a while before providing next location
            try {
                Thread.sleep(200);

                // gracefully handle Thread interruption (important!)
                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    throw new InterruptedException("");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                break;
            }

            // keep track of processed locations
            index++;
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "onProgressUpdate():"+values[0]);
        mMockGpsProviderIndex = values[0];
    }
}
```

}

I start the mockgps app, then press the home button to make it background. then I write another test application, and it can read the Latitude, Longitude, Altitude. But when I open the google map application, the google map always says that "can not locate". what's the problem?

thanks.